# WPF Chart Custom BarDataPoint ToolTip Show Duration

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, tooltip

I have a WPF Chart using BarSeries. I was trying to alter the default tooltip show duration of BarDataPoint.

I tried Adding Following Code in BarDataPointStyle Template:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="0"/>
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="30000"/>
```

But Didn't work.

Is there any way to change the default tooltip show duration of BarDataPoint?

Answer (score 0):

I just find out, by adding following code under `InitializeComponent();` solve the problem:

```
ToolTipService.ShowDurationProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Int32.MaxValue));
```

It works for me!